# Conversion from CString to char*/TCHAR*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, atl, cstring

I am well aware of techniques to convert `CString` to a C-style character. One of them is to use `strcpy`/`_tcscpy`, and others include using `CStrBuf`.

The problem:

```
char Destination[100];
CStringA Source; // A is for simplicity and explicit ANSI specification.

Source = "This is source string."
```

Now I want this:

```
Destination = Source;
```

To happen automatically. Well, that logically means writing a conversion operator in `CString` class. But, as implicit as it is, I dont have *privileges* to change the `CString` class.

I thought of writing a global conversion opertor and global assignment operator. But it doesnt work:

```
operator char* (const CStringA&); // Error - At least must be class-type
operator = ... // Won't work either - cannot be global.
```

Yes, it is definitely possible to write function (preferably a templated one). But that involves **calling** the function, and it is not smooth as assignment operator.

Comment: I'm not sure, but why can't you define a global `void operator=(char * & lhs, const CString & rhs)`? One of the arguments isn't a built-in type, so the overload should be possible.

Comment: @Kerrek: assignment must be overloaded as a non-static member function.

Comment: Can't you use GetBuffer(..) from the CString?

Comment: What use could be to assigning a `CString` to a fixed-size buffer?

Comment: @R. Mart: Oh, of course. Hm. Maybe you could abuse some other, rarely used operator that you *can* overload globally?

Comment: @Kerrek: Assignment operator cannot be global. It is by C++ rule-book.
-Simon: No my compiler raises error. Come on, I would use CSting directly, use operator LPCTSTR, but how to assign it directly to char-array, WITHOUT calling some function??
-ybung: To send the data over network, to save into binary file...

Comment: @Ajay: what? then you're doing something wrong. Use the *standard* `std::string str` and use `file.write(str.data(), str.size());` or the like. If you need padding, implement it as a separate function.

Comment: I love STL, but I hate this not-so-string class `std::string`. I don't even use it (For one, it is missing even basic convert-to-upper method!). Your suggestion doesn't solve the problem. The cahr-array data is packed in struct (with 1-byte pragma). I want to write less code, not more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't want to say that this is in any way recommendable, but you could hijack some lesser-used operator for a quick hack:

```
void operator<<=(char * dst, const std::string & s)
{
  std::strcpy(dst, s.c_str());
}

int main()
{
  char buf[100];
  std::string s = "Hello";

  buf <<= s;
}
```

You could even rig up a moderately safe templated version for statically sized arrays:

```
template <typename TChar, unsigned int N>
inline void operator<<=(TChar (&dst)[N], const std::string & s)
{
  std::strncpy(dst, s.c_str(), N);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Though not perfect solution (which is not possible anyway), but a very appreciating!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to arrays. This makes what you want impossible. Also, honestly, it's a pretty wrong thing to do - a magic-number-sized buffer?

Comment: Actually you aer right - even in class, we cannot return an array.

Answer (score 0):

An operator on `CString` won't solve the problem since you need to copy to `Destination` buffer although this assignment would change the value of Destination, which is impossible.

Somehow, you need an operator to achive this line:

```
strcpy(Destination, LPCSTR(Source)); // + buffer overflow protection
```

As you can see, converting Source is only half way. You still need to copy to the destination buffer.

Also, I wouldn't recommend it because the line `Destination = Source` is completely misleading in regard of the `char[]` semantics.

The only possible such assignment would be an initialisation of Destination:

```
char Destination[100] = Source;
```

Comment: If I could write the operator in `CString` class, I would have. And it is perfectly possible to copy to char/TCHAR array - just use template method, or pass additional size argument.